# MySQL left join - define / access aliased column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `months`, which stores some data for each calendar month:

```
id   name       (more...)
=========================
1    January    ...
2    February   ...
3    March      ...
..   ........   ...
```

I also have a table `schedule_event`. This contains fields: `id`, `name`, `start_date`, `end_date`. An event can be many months in duration.

On my frontend I output all events for a given month, in the following format:

> - January: Training, Planning
> - February: Planning
> - March: Team Meeting
> - April: (no events)

I use the following query to achieve this:

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  (CASE
    WHEN MAX(`se`.`name`) IS NOT NULL THEN GROUP_CONCAT(`se`.`name` ORDER BY `se`.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
    ELSE '(no events)'
  END) AS event_names

FROM
  month m

LEFT JOIN schedule_event se
  ON (
    (DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL (m.id - 1) MONTH BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date) OR
    (LAST_DAY(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL (m.id - 1) MONTH) BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date)
  )

GROUP BY m.id
```

This all works very well. But just one thing is bugging me - I am repeating the date calculation in the `ON` condition (`DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL (m.id - 1) MONTH`). This simply creates a date string from the `id`, so for example id 1 becomes `2021-01-01`.

Is it possible I can extract that and make it aliasable? I tried putting it in the `SELECT` and aliasing it, but it appears that the `ON` condition is unable to access aliased columns. I did consider assigning it as a variable, but eventually this query is going to be a MySQL VIEW, and unfortunately I cannot have user variables in a View.

Ideally I would like to put it in the JOIN itself, so I tried doing:

```
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT *, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL (m.id - 1) MONTH AS month_start_date
    FROM schedule_event
  ) AS se
  ON (
    (month_start_date BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date) OR
    (LAST_DAY(month_start_date) BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date)
  )
```

But this gives me error: `Unknown column 'm.id' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logic into `m`:

```
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL (m.id - 1) MONTH as this_year
       FROM month m
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     schedule_event se
     ON m.this_year BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date OR
        LAST_DAY(m.this_year) BETWEEN se.start_date AND se.end_date
```